# Getting undefined array key when using curl

Tags: php, laravel, curl

I'm building a simple domain availability checker using the [Godaddy api](https://developer.godaddy.com/doc/endpoint/domains#/v1/available).

I'm using Laravel 9 for the application.

It gives back available and already registered results, but if I add a string without domain extension like: somename
so no .com or.org etc. then I get an ("Undefined array key "available") error message.

On my view file I only have a simple form with one input field where the user can enter the domain name to be checked.

In my controller I validate the input:

```
$validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
   'userDomain' => ['required', 'string', 'max:191']
]);
```

I also have my API keys and base url stored in variables:

```
$API_KEY_OTE = "apikey";
$API_SECRET_OTE = "apisecret";
$OTE_BASE_URL = "https://api.ote-godaddy.com";
```

Then I remove some unwanted characters from the input

```
$request->userDomain = str_replace('www.', '', $request->userDomain);
$request->userDomain = str_replace('http://', '', $request->userDomain);
$request->userDomain = str_replace('https://', '', $request->userDomain);
```

I put together the url for curl like this:

```
$url = $OTE_BASE_URL . "/v1/domains/available?domain=" . $request->userDomain;
```

Then I have the curl settings like this:

```
$header = array(
    'Authorization: sso-key '.$API_KEY_OTE.':'.$API_SECRET_OTE.''
);

$ch = curl_init();
$timeout = 60;

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, $timeout);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER,false);  
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $header);

$result = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

$checkDomain = json_decode($result, true);
```

Then i check the result with a series of if / else if statements:

```
if($checkDomain['available'] == 1 || $checkDomain['available'] == true) {

            return redirect()->back()->with('successMsg',  'The domain name ' . $request->userDomain . ' is available! <a href="https://godaddy.com" target="_blank">Click here</a> to register it on Godaddy!');

        } else if($checkDomain['available'] == '' || $checkDomain['available'] == 0 || $checkDomain['available'] == false) {

            return redirect()->back()->with('failureMsg',  'Sorry! The domain name ' . $request->userDomain . ' is already registered! Try a different name.');
        }
        else if($checkDomain['code']) {
            return redirect()->back()->with('failureMsg',  $checkDomain['fields'][0]['message']);
        } else {
            return redirect()->back()->with('failureMsg',  'Please enter a valid domain name!');
        }
```

This is a successful response body that comes from godaddy:

```
{
  "available": true,
  "currency": "USD",
  "definitive": true,
  "domain": "string",
  "period": 0,
  "price": 0
}
```

and this is an invalid response body:

```
{
  "code": "string",
  "fields": [
    {
      "code": "string",
      "message": "string",
      "path": "string",
      "pathRelated": "string"
    }
  ],
  "message": "string"
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must first check if it's error response or success response, only then try to use one of it's keys:

```php
if (isset($checkDomain['available'])) {
    if (!empty($checkDomain['available'])) {
        return redirect()->back()->with('successMsg',  'The domain name ' . $request->userDomain . ' is available! <a href="https://godaddy.com" target="_blank">Click here</a> to register it on Godaddy!');
    }

    return redirect()->back()->with('failureMsg',  'Sorry! The domain name ' . $request->userDomain . ' is already registered! Try a different name.');
} elseif (isset($checkDomain['code'])) {
    return redirect()->back()->with('failureMsg',  $checkDomain['fields'][0]['message']);
}

return redirect()->back()->with('failureMsg',  'Please enter a valid domain name!');
```